# what are ProductName for iOS devices in MDM

Tags: ios, mdm

I have built a MDM server and is able to get the DeviceInformation command working. Now I would like to know what device I am talking to (is it iPhone 4s or 5). From the DeviceInformation command response, I get this from my iPhone 4s:

> ```
> <key>ProductName</key>
> <string>iPhone3,1</string>
> ```

And for my iPhone 5s, it is:

> ```
> <key>ProductName</key>
> <string>iPhone6,1</string>
> ```

What is the naming convention here? what about iPad/iPod/AppleTV?
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find information about models of iPhone and iPads [**here** (link corrected)](https://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models). The list is quite long. For example `iPad4,2` is iPad Air.

Below information about Apple TV.

- Apple TV - `AppleTV1,1`
- Apple TV 2G - `AppleTV2,1`
- Apple TV 3G - `AppleTV3,1` `AppleTV3,2`